# I am posting UTF-8 (Hindi) data via $.POST and getting this ( à¤®à¤¨à¤®à¥‹à¤¹à¤¨ à¤¸à¤¿à¤‚à¤¹ ) in my mysql db

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am posting UTF-8 (Hindi) data via `$.POST`. I am getting this: `à¤®à¤¨à¤®à¥‹à¤¹à¤¨ à¤¸à¤¿à¤‚à¤¹` in my MySQL database.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

is added in pages.

```
$.post("submit_answer_submit.php",
{
    qid: qidx,  
    answer: answerx
},
function(data, status){
```

How do I add "Content-Type:"?

Comment: Is this the `UTF-8 All The Way Through` question?

Comment: Yes sir UTF-8 All The Way, how to add Content-type in $.post (javascript)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058797/how-to-set-the-content-type-header-using-javascript  always search and research before posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved as i added "$result=mysqli_query($connn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");" before insert query in PHP